# Manage/group several Windows services at once?

Tags: windows, services

Is there any alternative to the  Windows 7 services.msc that allows managing the services in groups (instead of one by one) ?

Many programs install too many services.
I usually disable some to avoid wasting resources unnecessarily.

For example, I just installed SQL Server, and it came along with 6 different new services.
If you don't use them often you forget what services are related to what, and many services don't have a descriptive name.
Besides this, some services may be incompatible with others.
It can be tedious and time consuming to deal with them and remember the right combination.

I would like to find a simple program that allow to create profiles or enable/disable/star/manual/stop  several services at once or create profiles.

For example:
Profile 1 -> Enable services a, b + Disable p  +  Leave w, x, y, z  as they are.

Comment: Write batch files, using either `NET` or `SC`.  As-is this is just asking for a program that does "X", and software requests like that are off-topic for SU.  Perhaps rephrase your question to be about what you're trying to do instead of asking for a tool that does "X".  Include any research, and what you've attempted already.

Comment: What version of windows?

Comment: Windows 7.  I could provide a list of programs that manage services, such as windows 7 manager or tsm, but none of them do what I need.

Comment: I would suggest simply writing your own powershell scripts for this then.

Comment: Not sure why. It is dead simple to do.